# React Native Display Images in a Flatlist from a JSON array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, image-gallery

I am new in React. I could not find a way to display a list of images from the json array.

```html
    const [galleryIMG, setGalleryIMG] = useState(AuthVars.BLANK_IMAGE);
    
    useEffect(() => {
    Bootstrape.load().then((config) => {
    setAppConfig(config);
    });

    setGalleryIMG(post.gallery_uri ? post.gallery_uri : AuthVars.BLANK_IMAGE);}, []);'

    const getPostData = () => {
    console.log("getting post", post.postId);
    setLoading(true);
    PostsAPI.get(post.postId).then((data) => {
    setGalleryIMG(data.result[0].postmeta._job_gallery[0] === "" ? AuthVars.BLANK_IMAGE : data.result[0].postmeta._job_gallery[0]);
    setLoading(false);
    });
  };
```

Then in I display the image like this to display the first image from the array:

```html
<Image source={{ uri: galleryIMG }} style={styles.image} />
```

UPDATE

Now I use Gallery from react-native-gallery

```html
        
        import Gallery from 'react-native-image-gallery';

        <Gallery
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}
        onSingleTapConfirmed={() => setModalVisible(false)}
        images={[
          { source: { uri: galleryIMG[0] } },
          { source: { uri: galleryIMG[1] } },
          { source: { uri: galleryIMG[2] } }
        ]}
      />
```

How can I iterate galleryIMG to show all available images. As you can see I could only use it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Give data of image array to FlatList. Display image on render props of FL. give also some height and width to image.

Comment: <FlatList 
    data={galleryIMG}
    >
      <View style={{height: 200, width: "100%"}}>
      <Image source={{ uri: galleryIMG }} style={styles.gallery} />
      </View>
    </FlatList>

Comment: Pass the uri to source props of Image... can you share structure of galleryIMG array.? galleryIMG array is array of string then you can use like this `source={{uri:galleryIMG[index]}}` otherwise you need to iterate object key from array. Index will be second argument in render prop of FL